# docker-composer: services.networks Additional property <name of network> is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.9'
services:

    ... cut .. 

    # Docker Networks
    networks:
        app-network:
            driver: bridge
```

> services.networks Additional property app-network is not allowed

I am following this example

[image]

Found here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`networks:` is, along with `services:` a top level key.

You have defined a service called "networks", and services do not have a property called "app-network".

Comment: Damn, now I understand....  I added an indentation level !!!! Thanks